# Use of type() for method calls

Tags: python

Why does [PEP-343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) use type() in this situation here?

```
    mgr = (EXPR)
    exit = type(mgr).__exit__  # Not calling it yet
    value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
```

Couldn't we just as well use `exit = mgr.__exit__` and `value = mgr.__enter__()`? Seems simpler to me, but I assume I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course the PEP *could* use attributes of the instance itself instead of attributes of the type, but this would be in contrast to the use of special methods in Python.  For example

```
a + b
```

is translated to

```
type(a).__add__(a, b)
```

and **not** to

```
a.__add__(b)
```

as shown by the following example:

```
>>> class MyInt(int):
...     pass
... 
>>> a = MyInt(3)
>>> b = MyInt(4)
>>> a + b
7
>>> a.__add__ = lambda self, other: 42
>>> a + b
7
```

So, to be consistent with the rest of Python, the special methods `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` should also be looked up in the type's dictionary first.

Comment: Ok, so it's just a convention so that if someone changes the instances __dict__ we still call the original function. Didn't even think about that - have yet to find a situation where I'd want to do that ;) But if someone did, it'd lead to some strange behavior, so it makes sense.

Comment: @Voo: The rationale for the convention isn't avoiding strange behaviour -- you could still overwrite the `__add__()` method of the instance `a` by overriding its type with an on-the-fly type: `a.__class__ = type("", (type(a),), {"__add__": lambda self, other: 42})`.  Instead, the rationale for this behaviour is performance.  Special methods aren't looked up in the type's `__dict__`.  The internal type data structure rather provides special fields for pointers to the special methods, so they can be looked up much faster, see http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html#the-basics.

Comment: Do you mean the PyMethodDef array - which would still have to be searched through (but could be faster?)? Or is this just done so that we use one general method for all special methods, since some methods like tp_iternext profit from it since those are declared in the PyTypeObject?

Comment: @Voo: I don't understand your last question.  The look-up is faster because searching -- say -- `__iter__` in the type's dictionary would take much more time than simply directly accessing the `tp_iter` field of the type's [`PyTypeObject`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/type.html#PyTypeObject) structure.

Comment: That's what I mean. For __iter__ there'd be a noticeable improvement. But since there's no tp_enter we still have to search the PyMethodDef array don't we?

Comment: @Voo:  You are right -- `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` are indeed looked up in the type's dictionary, but most other special methods aren't.  So the performance argument only applies to the other methods, and `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` aren't looked up in the instance's dictionary for consistency.  (Of course skipping the instance during the look-up also warrants a small performance benefit).

Answer (score 2):

The above construct gets the *unbound* method of the type (class) of the `mgr` object, otherwise the `mgr` dict is acessed and you get the bound method.